# How to discover another app's intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to build an app to receive shares from the StumbleUpon app.
I can, at this point, receive the browser's "share url", but when sharing from StumbleUpon my app does not show up on the list.

I'm thinking that I may not have registered the correct Intents in the manifest.
Is there any way to find what that app is doing?

Thanks.

Comment: what intent are you declaring? something like <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter> ?

Comment: `code`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

<action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
`code`

Comment: your categories must be inside the actions

Comment: you mean like this?
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </action>
it doesn't even show up on the app tray

Comment: My bad. I don't know why I wrote this, it is completely wrong. May be putting different actions in different intent-filters, or defining a data type for the action ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a bit of information about intents from logcat.  When I shared in StumbleUpon I noticed this in the log:

```
12-08 19:01:18.915: I/ActivityManager(139): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail (has extras) } from pid 4213
```

From that, I was able to get an app to show up in the StumbleUpon share list with the following filter:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Looks like many intents are registered dynamically in code and do not have to be defined in manifest :-/